# How can I print number in 4 digit?

Tags: php

I want to print a list of numbers in php.
But I want to print 4 digits of numbers (preceding with zero if necessary), e.g.
0001, 0009, 0076, 0129, 1234

What should I do?

Comment: What if the original number has more than four digits?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
printf("%04d", $num);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
printf ('%04d' ,$num)
```

Answer (score 1):

[printf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [PHP Language Reference Manual](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and search for zero-padded integers

The link gives the `sprintf` details, but the format string information applies to related functions like `printf`